# Surrounding an equilateral triangle

Tags: mathematics, geometry, triangle

You are given an equilateral triangle. What is the most number of such identical triangles you can place such that they do not overlap, but each one touches the original triangle?

Comment: Does a shared vertex count as touching?

Comment: @DanielMathias a shared vertex counts as touching, but not as overlapping. I hope that helps.

Comment: The solutions seems trivial? I'll have to think on it after answering the knights question.

Comment: The solution may well be trivial. This is not meant to be a difficult puzzle.

Comment: you should also mention that all the triangles should be in the same plane as that of the original traingle .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trivial solution?

> 12 triangles:
>  [image]

Comment: That's it. You have found the kissing number for the triangle.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can fit

> An Infinite #
>  Place a triangle next to the original one so one edge is fully adjacent
>  Place a second triangle along that same edge, fully adjacent, but lift the far vertex   vertically off the plane a bit so the new triangle rotates in 3-D
>  Place a third triangle along that same edge, but between the first two
>  Continue indefinitely. You will have an effect like the pages of a book spread open in a fan.
>  [image]